# Python: Trying to extract a value from a list of dictionaries that is stored as a string

Tags: python, json, api

I am getting data from an API and storing it in json format. The data I pull is in a list of dictionaries. I am using Python. My task is to only grab the information from the dictionary that matches the ticker symbol.

This is the short version of my data printing using json dumps

```
[
    {
        "ticker": "BYDDF.US",
        "name": "BYD Co Ltd-H",
        "price": 25.635,
        "change_1d_prc": 9.927101200686117
    },
    {
        "ticker": "BYDDY.US",
        "name": "BYD Co Ltd ADR",
        "price": 51.22,
        "change_1d_prc": 9.843448423761526
    },
    {
        "ticker": "TSLA.US",
        "name": "Tesla Inc",
        "price": 194.7,
        "change_1d_prc": 7.67018746889343
    }
]
```

Task only gets the dictionary for ticker = TSLA.US. If possible, only get the price associated with this ticker.

I am unaware of how to reference "ticker" or loop through all of them to get the one I need.

I tried the following, but it says that its a string, so it doesn't work:

```
   if "ticker" == "TESLA.US":
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (mylist is your list of dictionaries)

```
for entry in mylist:
    print(entry['ticker'])
```

Then try this to get what you want:

```
for entry in mylist:
    if entry['ticker'] == 'TSLA.US':
        print(entry)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So when Irun this code it gives me the following error.

TypeError: string indices must be integers

If I check the type of the variable in which I am storing the data it says its a string not a list

Comment: My code works fine with your data if it is a list of dictionaries as you say. You can now see how to access specific elements. So you challenge now is to get the data from whatever format it is in into a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that I've seen divide the python community. Some say that it's a feature and "very pythonic"; others say that it's a bad design choice we're stuck with now, and bad practice. I'm personally not a fan, but it is a way to solve this problem, so do with it what you will. :)

Python function loops aren't a new scope; the loop variable persists even after the loop. So, either of these are a solution. Assuming that your list of dictionaries is stored as `json_dict`:

```
for target_dict in json_dict:
    if target_dict["ticker"] == "TESLA.US":
        break
```

At this point, `target_dict` will be the dictionary you want.

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I have the issue where my result is stored in a variable with type string not a list of dictionaries. I don't know how to alter that. This is how I am printing out the json. 

```     
response = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielatuesta55/MSBA_502_and_503/main/second_final_project")
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))```

Comment: Do you know how I can store the API hit as a JSON Dic?

Comment: If you're using the requests library, you can just use `result = requests.get(url); result.json()`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to iterate through a list of dictionaries using a for loop.

```
    for stock in list:
        if stock["ticker"] == "TSLA.US":
            return stock["price"]
```

This essentially loops through every item in the list, and for each item (which is a dictionary) looks for the key "ticker" and checks if its value is equal to "TSLA.US". If it is, then it returns the value associated with the "price" key.